# Modifying a color chooser panel

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

I am creating a colour chooser and need to modify one of the colour chooser panels.

[image: Color Chooser]

What I wanted was, I want to enter input values via the RGB fields to set the colour,The problem is the RGB values seem to be disabled is there a method within the api to turn on the RGB inputs to take a value?

Comment: where is disabled RGB Color model, please post an http://sscce.org/ that demonstate your issues

Comment: It does not look disabled to me.  Did you try clicking on the RGB tab or typing Ctrl G?

Comment: Andrew, it's Alt+G, I think :-)

Comment: @Joey  You are correct.  Oops, my bad.  ;)

Comment: I purposely disabled the RGB panel,I wanted to input the RGB values on the HSB panel. Are those RGB values just labels or are they disabled text fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems fine here.

[image: Color Chooser Test]

```
import javax.swing.*;

class ColorChooserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JColorChooser());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

> Is there anyway you can combine the RGB slider panel and the HSB panel?

Yes, apparently it is possible.  Check this (very fragile, poorly laid out) example.

[image: Color Chooser Test 2]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class ColorChooserTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JColorChooser cc = new JColorChooser();
                AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = cc.getChooserPanels();

                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                panels[1].setBorder(
                    new TitledBorder(panels[1].getDisplayName()));
                p.add(panels[1]);

                panels[2].setBorder(
                    new TitledBorder(panels[2].getDisplayName()));
                p.add(panels[2]);

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));
                gui.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                gui.add(cc.getPreviewPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there anyway you can combine the rgb slider panel and the hsb panel?.I was just after a color chooser with only one panel.

Comment: I don't know, but it is an odd requirement.  As a user I'd want to see them separated.

Comment: +1 for `getChooserPanels()`. I've never been sanguine about relying on the index, and the classes are package private. I finally settled on searching for `panel.getClass().getSimpleName()`.