# Using ColorPanel from JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcolorchooser

So in second (HSV) tab, default `JColorChooser` has several elements, two of them being colorful and rest sliders and spinners.

I want to use only the two colorful elements, which I have identified as `ColorPanel` *(at least one of them)*. But those classes aren't **public** and I can't access them.

Is there a way to use them anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually access them through a color chooser like so:

```
 JColorChooser cc = new JColorChooser();
 AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = cc.getChooserPanels();
```

Also check out this question:
[Modifying a color chooser panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999786/modifying-a-color-chooser-panel/9000014#9000014)

Comment: I don't want that. I want to extract a part of panels[1] and use it independently of whole JColorChooser.